# Query in SQL Server 2012 - get a substring

Tags: sql-server-2012

In our tool, we use an expression `[&SEARCHFIELDS]` which converts the UI search criteria into respective SQL Server equivalent code.

In my case it is converted in to the following:

```
( (CONVERT(DateTime, CONVERT(Varchar(16), ORD.DATBEGIN, 126) + ':00.000' , 126) BETWEEN (CONVERT(DateTime, CONVERT(Varchar(16), Convert(datetime,'2016-07-01 00:00:00',21), 126) + ':00.000' , 126)) AND ( CONVERT(DateTime, CONVERT(Varchar(16), Convert(datetime,'2016-07-13 23:59:59',21), 126) + ':00.000' , 126)))  AND  (ORD.SYSOBJALG = ( 5000088)) )
```

I want to get `5000088` substring from the above long string, I tried using `SELECT RIGHT('Above expression',11)` but it is throwing errors as there are multiple single quotes within the above long expression.

Can someone help me?

Comment: This query looks hideous, could you show us the input string and what you are trying to extract?

Comment: It itself is the string...

Comment: It itself is the string...it's a unique requirement, I want to use the substring in the above query/ substring elsewhere @Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: This would best be handled outside of SQL. How does it build this statement? It has to be multiple parts, no?